# Unable to set font size with asciidoctor-pdf

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

I'm unable to set a font size (or style) for my .adoc files when transformed in PDF with asciidoctor-pdf.
According to the docs, I can specify it as follows:

```
base:
  font_size: 8
  line_height_length: 10
```

So I've put it at the top of my .adoc file. However the resulting PDF does not reflect this change. Can you provide an .adoc file as an example, which specifies a different font size or style?
Thanjs

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of any way of doing it inside the `.adoc` file.

You must put the style outside the asciidoctor file.

*some-document.adoc*

```
= The title
:pdf-theme: some-theme.yml

First paragraph

Second paragraph
```

*some-theme.yml*

```
extends: default
base:
  font_size: 8
  line_height_length: 10
  font-color: #ff0000
```

Build with:

```
$ asciidoctor-pdf some-document.adoc -o some-document.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried using it, although the font size does not vary, whatever I add in the yaml file.

Comment: Is the text any red ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've tried also copying and pasting your documents as they are but the font or color does not vary. I assume then that I'm missing some libs in my asciidoctor installation

Comment: OK, I double-check on my side and it's definitely working. If you are familiar with Docker, you can use their image (https://github.com/asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor). It really ease the usage.