# Can I change the font used in source blocks by Asciidoctor PDF?

Tags: asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

Is it possible to specify a different font for use in the `source` blocks of a PDF generated by `asciidoctor-pdf`?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the theme I'm using (currently just the default), but I've checked the [theming guide](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/docs/theming-guide.adoc) and can't see any configuration related to the `source` blocks specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible and yes it has to do with the theming. You can check the default asciidoctor-pdf theming under https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/data/themes/default-theme.yml, you will see line 188 `# code is used for source blocks (perhaps change to source or listing?)`, this is what you need to change.

The simplest way is to create your own theme `custom-theme.yml` by **extending the default theme** and set the font family you want, in my example *Courier*, this works:

```
extends: default
font:
  catalog:
    merge: true
    Courier:
      normal: cour.ttf
      bold: courbd.ttf
      italic: couri.ttf
      bold_italic: courbi.ttf
code:
  font_family: Courier
```

I organize my files like this:

```
yourFile.adoc
resources/themes/custom-theme.yml
resources/fonts/cour.ttf
resources/fonts/courbd.ttf
resources/fonts/couri.ttf
resources/fonts/courbi.ttf
```

You then need to call `asciidoctor-pdf` with your new theme and a link to the fonts path, something like this:

```
asciidoctor-pdf -a pdf-theme=resources/themes/custom-theme.yml -a pdf-fontsdir="resources/fonts;GEM_FONTS_DIR" yourFile.adoc
```

Comment: If anyone gets here, there's a straight-forward example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58984917/722238